# Distribution of loans by types of interest

Tags: data, statistics, floating-rate

Im looking for some kind of **report** that would inculde data on the distribution of **corporate loans** by types of interest(**fixed/floating**), specifically **global** not just for one country(developed, undeveloped, developing world). If any of you have known to stumble upon such reports would be grand.

Comment: There are still quite a lot of loans that fit this criteria, you may want to specify which type, e.g. single-family residential mortgage loans, loans to people by their credit history, corporate loans, etc.

Comment: Why do you need this information?